# Unable to resolve database with sitecore SES when adding to shopping Cart

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore-ecommerce

I am using SES with Sitecore.
I got an issue when adding an item to the shopping cart.
This is the trace I got:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve database.]
    Sitecore.Ecommerce.Prices.ProductPriceManager.get_Database() +244
    Sitecore.Ecommerce.Prices.ProductPriceManager.GetPriceMatrixPrice(TProduct product, String priceMatrixName) +129
    Sitecore.Ecommerce.Prices.ProductPriceManager.GetProductTotals(TProduct product, TCurrency currency, UInt32 quantity) +391
    Sitecore.Ecommerce.Carts.ShoppingCartManager.AddProduct(String productCode, UInt32 quantity) +552
    Neo.Business.OrderServices.AddToShoppingCart(String productCode, String quantity) in c:\Projets\NeoSiteCore\Neo.Business\PaymentServices.cs:92
    Neo.WebSites.Layouts.NeoSublayouts.OnlineCourses.AddToCartForm.AddToCartButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in  c:\Projets\NeoSiteCore\Neo.WebSites\Layouts\NeoSublayouts\OnlineCourses\AddToCartForm.ascx.cs:70
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +153
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

It must be that the price calculation is causing the issue.
I modified the default price matrix items in Sitecore, that's just what I did.
Can you give me ideas please?

Comment: Was it working before you modified the price matrix? The stack trace suggests the ProductPriceManager was not initialized properly. Could you provide more info about what's going on in Neo.Business.OrderServices

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  We are experiencing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from Sitecore support that fixed the issue.  In my site configuration below I was missing **content="master"**.  Not sure why I need it, but it fixes the problem.

```
<site name="website" 
        virtualFolder="/" 
        physicalFolder="/" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content" 
        startItem="/home" 
        database="web" 
        domain="extranet" 
        allowDebug="true" 
        cacheHtml="true" 
        htmlCacheSize="10MB" 
        registryCacheSize="0" 
        viewStateCacheSize="0" 
        xslCacheSize="5MB" 
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
        enablePreview="true" 
        enableWebEdit="true" 
        enableDebugger="true" 
        disableClientData="false"
        EcommerceSiteSettings="/Ecommerce/Site Settings"
        ordersDatabase="orders" 
        actionLogDatabase="logging"
        content="master"
        />
```